# Create a country code dropdown as in Google Contacts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I google around for a javascript plugin which works similar to country code dropdown in Google Contacts but to no vail. Someone having worked on this kind of control please provide a hint/link to it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have a look @ http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan Very good plugin! I'll use it as starting point for my control. Thank very much! If you put your answer instead of this comment, I will accept it right away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good plugin:

[International Telephone Input](http://jackocnr.com/intl-tel-input.html)

Have fun.